# Batch elements of the List based on the parameter's value

Tags: java, list, arraylist, batch-processing

```
private List<PoI> batch(List<PoI> _POIs)
{
    List<PoI> _POIs_batched = new ArrayList<PoI>();
    for (PoI poi1 : _POIs) 
    {
        for (PoI poi2 : _POIs) 
        {
            if (poi1.getId() == poi2.getId())
            {
                PoI newPoI = new PoI(poi1.getId(),poi1.getServiceTime()+poi2.getServiceTime());
                _POIs_batched.add(newPoI);
            }
        }
    }

    return _POIs_batched;
}
```

I need to find and batch elements that have the same getId() value. The problem of the above-given code is that I am searching pairs of elements. However, there might be more than 2 elements that have the same getId() value.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map<Integer, List<PoI>>` (I assumed id is `int`- or `Integer`-typed; anyway, if it is an `Integer`, please use `.equals()` instead of `==`).

You can keep lists of `PoI`s sharing the same id. Then, you can add up their service times easily.

EDIT (CODE SNIPPET):

```
Map<Integer, List<PoI>> poisPerId = new HashMap<>();
for (PoI poi : _POIs){
    Integer id = poi.getId();
    List<PoI> pois = poisPerId.get(id);
    if(pois == null){
        pois = new ArrayList<PoI>();
        poisPerId.put(id, pois);
    }
    pois.add(poi);
}
```